# Splitting text to column

Tags: shell, unix, awk

i have case to splitting text like sample

```
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0
AE|B1|CC|DE| |EX|FF|0
AR|BE|CA|D1| 5#6#3#;4#3#4;|ED|G|
```

I need the text to be like this

```
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|3|1|1
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|1|4|4
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|5|1|4
AE|B1|CC|DE| |EX|FF|0|||
AR|BE|CA|D1| 5#6#3#;4#3#4;|ED|G||5|6|3
AR|BE|CA|D1| 5#6#3#;4#3#4;|ED|G||4|3|4
```

i already try using

> awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {split($5,a,/;/); for (i in a) {if (a[i])
> $9=a[i]; else next; gsub(/#/,"|",$9); print}}

however the if the $5 is having space only, it wont adding the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    tgt = ( /;/ ? $2 : "###;")
    gsub(/#/,"|",tgt)
    n = split(tgt,a,/\|?;/)
    for ( i=1; i<n; i++ ) {
        print $0 "|" a[i]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|3|1|1
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|1|4|4
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|5|1|4
AE|B1|CC|DE| |EX|FF|0|||
AR|BE|CA|D1| 5#6#3#;4#3#4;|ED|G||5|6|3
AR|BE|CA|D1| 5#6#3#;4#3#4;|ED|G||4|3|4
```

Comment: defaulting with "###;" saves a lot of keystrokes, nice!

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
match($0,/(([0-9]+#)+);[^|]*/){
  num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,";")
  for(i=1;i<num;i++){
    sub(/#$/,"",arr[i])
    gsub(/#/,"|",arr[i])
    print $0"|"arr[i]
  }
  next
}
{
  print $0 "|||"
}
'   Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using function approach in `awk`, with your shown samples please try following `awk` code. We can pass number of fields into function what we want to look and get values for, eg: in this case I am passing 2nd, 3rd and 4th field numbers into the function to work on them to get required output. But in case you have too many fields then I suggest use the 1st solution of mine shown above.

```
awk -F' |;' '
function getValues(fields){
  num=split(fields,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if($arr[i]~/^([0-9]+#)+[0-9]*$/){
      val=$arr[i]
      sub(/#$/,"",val)
      gsub(/#/,"|",val)
      print $0"|"val
    }
  }
}
/([0-9]+#)+;/{
  getValues("2,3,4")
  next
}
{
  print $0 "|||"
}
'   Input_file
```

---

In both the solutions, output will be as follows:

```
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|3|1|1
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|1|4|4
A|B|C|D| 3#1#1#;1#4#4;5#1#4;|E|F|0|5|1|4
AE|B1|CC|DE| |EX|FF|0|||
AR|BE|CA|D1| 5#6#3#;4#3#4;|ED|G||5|6|3
AR|BE|CA|D1| 5#6#3#;4#3#4;|ED|G||4|3|4
```